# True or False in c programming pertaining to while loop

Tags: c

Can someone explain true false in c programming pertaining to this while loop?

If 0 is false Done=0, and `while (!Done)` is suppose to be true and done = 1 is also true, then how does done=1 cause the loop to "break" or exit?

```
    done=0;
    while(!done)
    {
        c=getchar();
        switch(c)
        {
            case '1': 
            printf("Beverage  $8.00\n");
            total+= 8;
            break;

            case '2':
            printf("Candy       $3.00\n");
            total+= 3;
            break;

            case '3':
            printf("Sandwich $5.00\n");
            total+= 5;
            break;

            case '4':
            printf("Hot Dog.   $2.00\n");
            total+= 2;
            break;

            case '5':
            printf("Popcorn    $6.00\n");
            total+= 6;
            break;

            case '=':
            printf("Your choices are finished.\n");
            printf("The total is:$%.2f\n", total);
            printf("Please pay the cashier.\n");
            done=1;
            break;

            default:
            printf("I don't understand your choice, please try again.\n");
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If `done` is non-zero, then as a boolean value `done` is `true`. Thus `!done` will be `false` and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow M.B.

A `while` loop in C evaluates whatever is in it as either `true` or `false`, before every loop.

One of the guarantees you get when programming in C is that **only 0 is false**, and **everything else is true**. That means that `foobar` is true, `64` is true, `-1` is true, and in your case, `1` is true.

Because of this, the `!` operator (the `not` symbol), it changes anything that is true into a `0`, and changes a `0` into a `1`.

Therefore, what your while loop is really doing is saying:
"While not done"
or "While done is not true"
or "While done is false"
or "While done is 0"

So when your last case statement of `'='` is hit, and the code `done=1;` is run, you code will exit the next time it comes around and checks the condition for the while loop.

Comment: So when !done is !0, which is true but done=1 is also true so I still don't understand all the way. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> while(done != 1)

, currently done = `0` so it will be `true` as done is not equals to `1`, once you set done = `1`, it will return `false` and exit the loop.

Comment: While this will result in the code doing the same thing (in this case), it is not logically equivalent. You'd be better to say `while(done == 0)`.

Comment: I agree with this way of coding it, but this doesn't answer my original question all the way.  Why does done=1 turn !done false in the while loop?

Comment: @M.B. hmmm that i'm not too sure but it seems that anything other than 0 will return true, but it is not a good practice to code like that.

Comment: I just had a light bulb moment, lol. I get it now, but I agree that this way is not the easiest to understand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Initially done is 0 so !done is !0 wich is 1 
so its true, inside the loop when  done is set to 1 !done is 0 and the loop ends

Comment: So when !done is !0, which is true but done=1 is also true so I still don't understand all the way